# Method that returns one of two types in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following method that is supposed to return a component object if it's previously been registered

```
/**
 * Retrieve a component
 * @param       string      sComponentName      The name of the component to look for
 * @return      ComponentInterface | boolean
 */
public getComponent(sComponentName: string): boolean | ComponentInterface {
    if(!this.hasComponent(sComponentName)) {
        return false;
    }

    return this.components[sComponentName];
}
```

Everything compiles and runs fine but my editor is throwing the following warning...

```
Property 'x' does not exist on type 'boolean | ComponentInterface'
```

when I try to run...

```
const oPositionComponent = oEntity.getComponent('position');
console.log(oPositionComponent.x);
```

Is there a better way of writing this so that my editor knows what I'm trying to achieve?

---

**Solution**

Ok, so since I was actually checking the existence of the component in the previous step I just type-casted the return value...

```
aEntities = aEntities.filter((oEntity) => {
    return oEntity.hasComponent('position');
});

aEntities.forEach((oEntity) => {
    const oPositionComponent = <ComponentInterface> oEntity.getComponent('position');
    this.context.translate(oPositionComponent.x, oPositionComponent.y);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it may return `false` compiler assumes oPositionComponent.x may fail in this case. 
You may assert the type (if you're sure you'd get the component and not false:

```
console.log((<ComponentInterface>oPositionComponent).x);
```

But in production-quality code you should deal with possible false returns via [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) :

```
if (oPositionComponent instanceof ComponentInterface) { // this will only work with classes, not interfaces (?)
    console.log(oPositionComponent.x);
} else { // this must be false
    console.log("component is not registered");
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. I was actually already explicitly checking that the component exists in the previous step so I ended up just type-casting the return value (see edit)

Comment: Note that type casting using `<Type>variable` is legacy because of JSX. Use `variable as Type`.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha it is not legacy. In `.ts` files you can use either syntax and neither is deprecated. In `.tsx` files, you must use `as`. Personally, I think `value as Type` reads slightly better but `<Type>value` is in no way legacy.